# Pass data-id or key to onClick function

Tags: reactjs

I have buttons created in a loop. Each contains a `key` and `data-id` property.
I want to `onClick` pass the `key` or `data-id` to the called function.
I experimented a few things, but none worked.
Here is the code.

```
buttonPress: function (path,type,period) {
    AppActions.moveToPage(path,{type:type},period);
},



<div key={$key} data-id={$key} style={{textAlign: 'center'}} onClick={() => this.buttonPress("Listing",this.props.id, this.state.filters)}>{this.state.Graph?this.state.diagnosisGraph[key]:<img src={AppApi.baseUrl + 'img/loading.gif'} />}</div>
```

Comment: Why not just pass $key to this.buttonPress function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly pass the $key to the mouse down function

```
buttonPress: function (path,type,period,key) {
AppActions.moveToPage(path,{type:type},period);
},



<div key={$key} data-id={$key} onClick={() => this.buttonPress("Listing",this.props.id, this.state.filters, key)}>{this.state.Graph?this.state.diagnosisGraph[key]:<img src={AppApi.baseUrl + 'img/loading.gif'} />}</div>
```